# Location of Recent Apps screenshot directory

Tags: screenshots, recents-screen

Where does "Recent Apps" in Android store the screenshots?

I have seen a couple of threads on how to prevent these screenshots from being taken. But I would like to know the location of the screenshots directory.

Comment: Please clarify question a little bit.

Comment: Guess he talks about the "recently used apps" list popping up when long-pressing the home button. On tablets with 4.1 up (if not even earlier) this no longer shows the icon only, but a screenshot of the app's last state. Not being able to root my new tabby (yet), I could not check yet for those files...

Comment: The screenshot facility, **cannot be** taken out as that is integrated directly into the AOSP source which when compiled produces a Stock AOSP Vanilla ROM, and applies only to ICS upwards, on previous versions, it required root to do this.

Comment: @t0mm13b the question is not about removing the functionality, but about locating the screenshot image files. I just browsed through the entire internal file systems of my Wildfire (ICS), but was not able to find them. Any idea of where they might be stored? Being thumbnails only, I could imagine them being stored directly into the media database, if that's possible with SQLite.

Comment: Hmmm... try `/sdcard/DCIM/Screenshots`? :D

Answer (score 1):

On my Nexus devices `/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots`

I think it's the default, odd really as it should go in with DCIM

Comment: DCIM is the de-facto standard for the location for pictures taken with camera... :) Hence the separation for screenshots..

Comment: But that `Screenshots` directory is not the one the OP asked for: Here are the screenshots saved which the user *explicitly*  takes using the volume and power key combination. OP was asking for the screenshots shown in the "recent apps" menu.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 phone it's also `/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots`

The fact that it's in the same place on two different devices suggests that it's an Android standard, rather than something left up to the device manufacturer.

Comment: Actually that path is where manually taken screenshots are stored. It has nothing to do with "Recently Used Apps" screenshots.

Comment: OK, good point. I haven't seen "Recently Used Apps" screen shots before, so I overlooked that when I tried to answer the question.